# Flutter FutureBuilder always return null

Tags: flutter, dart

FutureBuilder keep returning null even when the http request successfully fetch the data from api.

I use json_serializable and freezed package in my data model, is this error related to them or it is purely coming from flutter/dart?

Http request

```dart
  Future<VitalSignResponse> getLatestVitalSign(String medicalNo) async {
    final String url = Api.baseUrl +
        'VitalSignByMedicalNoLatest?AccessKey=${Api.accessKey}&MedicalNo=$medicalNo';

    Response res = await Dio().get(url);

    print('api res: ${res.data}'); // 'api res: the correct data from api'
    print('serialize: ${VitalSignResponse.fromJson(json.decode(res.data))}'); // print out nothing

    return VitalSignResponse.fromJson(json.decode(res.data));
  }
```

data model

```dart
@freezed
abstract class VitalSignResponse with _$VitalSignResponse {
  @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
  const factory VitalSignResponse(
    final String status,
    final String errorCode,
    final List<VitalSign> data,
  ) = _VitalSignResponse;

  factory VitalSignResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$VitalSignResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

future builder logic

```dart
FutureBuilder(
        future: service.getLatestVitalSign(patientBloc.patient.medicalNo),
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
        ) {
          print(snapshot.data); // null

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // show data
          }

          return Container();
        },
      ),
```

Comment: `print(VitalSignResponse.fromJson(json.decode(res.data)))` what do you see? something non null?

Comment: @pskink it print out nothing to the console

Comment: @pskink still nothing

Comment: @pskink yes i don't see the `serialize: ` at all.

Comment: @pskink i posted in the answer what i can found related to fromJson method in the *.g.dart file

Comment: so where does it block? tried to debug that code?

Comment: @pskink ah yes, i've been running the project without debugging so that's why it doesn't catch any error. Thankyou for pointing out and sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

## I simply forgot to run my project with debugging

i leave the question here as a personal reminder and for new developer out there to not making the same mistake i did. And for my friends to laugh at me haha